# Filtering option causing python to hang - how to debug?

Tags: pandas, filtering

I am preprocessing large datasets to get them ready for clustering operations. I have a script that reads the data from CSV and performs various checks for missing data, erroneous values, etc. Until now, everything has worked as expected. Still, when I ran the script yesterday, it started to hang on to a simple filtering operation. The source data has not changed, but somehow processing can't get past this line. I have isolated the problem by moving the following lines of code to another file, and the same issue is observed:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data1.csv',index_col=0)
# Get list of columns of interest for first check
columns = [col for col in df.columns if 'temp' in col]
# Find indices where any value of a column of interest has a value of 1
indices = list(df[df[columns]==1].dropna(how='all').index)
```

This previously ran fine, correctly identifying indices with this '1' flag in 'columns'. Now (and with no changes to the code or source data), it hangs on the indices line. I further broke it down to identify the specific problem: `df[columns]==1` runs fine, but grabbing the `df` filtered on this condition (`df[df[columns]==1]`) is the line that hangs.

How can I troubleshoot what the problem is? Since I had not made any changes when it last worked, I am perplexed. What could possibly be the cause? Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: can you share a sample of the data?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not an easy way for me to share a sample of the data; it's confidential and quite large. For troubleshooting, I have now taken only the first 200 rows of the df and performed the same operations, I then broke it down into the several operations to time them: df[columns]==1 takes 0.0066 seconds. I then save this to a new variable 'chk' and perform the next operation, df[chk1] which takes 15.96 seconds. The final operation (.dropna(how='all').index) takes 0.24 seconds. Thus, it's definitely this step where the df is filtered based on the boolean area generated in step 1

Comment: I seem to have solved this problem by taking a more direct approach to obtaining the indices where there is a 1 in any of the columns, see now my new edit above.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The below approach seems to be drastically faster and solved the problem:

indices = df[(df[columns]==1).any(1)].index
When tested on a subset of the whole df, it accomplished the task in 0.015 seconds, while the prior method took 15.0 seconds.